# What's an easy way to print a multi-line string without variable substitution in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program that reads in a bunch of data, munges it, and then outputs several different file formats. I'd like to make Perl be one of those formats (in the form of a .pm package) and allow people to use the munged data within their own Perl scripts.

Printing out the data is easy using [Data::Dump::pp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dump).

I'd also like to print some helper functions to the resulting package.

What's an easy way to print a multi-line string ***without*** variable substitution?

I'd like to be able to do:

```
print <<EOL;
  sub xyz { 
    my $var = shift;
  }
EOL
```

But then I'd have to escape all of the $'s.

Is there a simple way to do this? Perhaps I can create an actual sub and have some magic pretty-printer print the contents? The printed code doesn't have to match the input or even be legible.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Data::Dump::Streamer as its more accurate than Data::Dumper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your code as an actual perl subroutine, then using [B::Deparse](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/ext/B/B/Deparse.pm) to get the source code at runtime.

Comment: B::Deparse will not properly capture closures, which are more common than one might think.  Use Data::Dump::Streamer.

Comment: @Schwern: B::Deparse does one thing with closures (assume the eval context is correct), Data::Dump::Streamer does another (assume any closed over variables aren't used by anything but the dumped code).  Neither could be said to be "not proper".

Comment: If you're creating an actual Perl subroutine, don't stringify it at all. Make it a library. This isn't a game of Mousetrap :)

Answer (score 41):

Enclose the name of the delimiter in single quotes and interpolation will not occur.

```
print <<'EOL';
  sub xyz { 
    my $var = shift;
  }
EOL
```

Comment: That's ok I guess I'll have to cry myself to sleep on top of a freakishly large pile of reputation points

Answer (score 4):

You could use a templating package like [Template::Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/) or [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Template/).

Or, you could roll your own primitive templating system that looks something like this:

```
my %vars = qw( foo 1 bar 2 );
Write_Code(\$vars);

sub Write_Code {
    my $vars = shift;

    my $code = <<'END';

    sub baz {
        my $foo = <%foo%>;
        my $bar = <%bar%>;

        return $foo + $bar;
    }

END

    while ( my ($key, $value) = each %$vars ) {
        $code =~ s/<%$key%>/$value/g;
    }

    return $code;
}
```

This looks nice and simple, but there are various traps and tricks waiting for you if you DIY.  Did you notice that I failed to use quotemeta on my key names in the substituion?

I recommend that you use a time-tested templating library, like the ones I mentioned above.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use a template module. Please don't roll your own :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can actually continue a string literal on the next line, like this:

```
my $mail = "Hello!

Blah blah.";
```

Personally, I find that more readable than heredocs (the `<<<EOL` thing mentioned elsewhere).

Double quote " interpolates variables, but you can use '. Note you'll need to escape any ' in your string for this to work.

Perl is actually quite rich in convenient things to make things more readable, e.g. other quote-operations. qq and q correspond to " and ' and you can use whatever delimiter makes sense:

```
my $greeting = qq/Hello there $name!
Nice to meet you/;  # Interpolation

my $url = q|http://perlmonks.org/|;     # No need to escape /
```

(note how the syntax coloring here didn't quite keep up)

Read `perldoc perlop` (find in page: "Quote and Quote-like Operators") for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use a data section to store the Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print <DATA>;
#print munged data

__DATA__
package MungedData;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo {
    print "foo\n";
}
```